# What's this "auto attached" behavior called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is a feature when we use tools like [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) or PowerPoint.

As you can see below, I have two rectangles on the canvas.
When I drag the green one close enough to the blue one, the green one will be auto attached to the blue one like a magnet.

What's this "auto attached" behavior called in English?
Is there a proper noun for it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word used in most software I've seen is "snapping". For example, [one Microsoft Office support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-the-snap-to-grid-and-snap-to-object-options-on-or-off-817da2d4-40cc-4cff-b0de-1359ecbe95e3) says the following:

> When you draw, resize, or move a shape or other object in Excel, PowerPoint, or Word, you can set it so that it will align or "snap” to the nearest intersection in the grid (even if the grid is not visible) or snap to other shapes or objects.